# I cant echo with php

Tags: php

Hello I am very new to php and I am all ready experiencing errors.
I am simply trying to make php display hello world inside the  header tag.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    echo <h1>"Hello World"</h1>
  ?>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Everything to the right of echo goes in quotes.

Comment: what hello world tutorial are you following

Comment: Are you new to computer programming in general?

Comment: Yes i am very new to programming

Comment: You shouldn't put `<h1>` in header tag.

Comment: what the hell are you doing? you should put all the statemens in echo inside ""  example : "<h1>Hello World</h1>"hahahah..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with you should really do more research before you post here. A simple google search could have helped you.
Your header tags should be inside of the quotation marks. Also you need to close the echo with a semi-colon at the end of the line.

```
<?php
echo "<h1>This is a correct echo.</h1>";
?>
```

Also if you need help learning PHP use the resource on the web.
[Help with echo in php](http://www.w3resource.com/php/echo-print/echo.php)
[Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/)

You can also use [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) to learn php.

Comment: This is working thank you. I will use these sites to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

You did't encase the string correctly:

```
echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
```

If you need to keep the quotes:

```
echo "<h1>&quot;Hello World&quot;</h1>";
```

Comment: +1 for being the only one to observe that the quotes may be part of he raw string.

Comment: @Herbert, Haha. Thanks. I'm a pretty literal person I guess.

Comment: or, to [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle): [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities).

Answer (score 2):

within `<?php` and `?>` you're in code. That means, if it's not a keyword or a form of coding structure, it needs to be syntactically correct in terms of php language (and HTML outside of a declared string is not correct). e.g.

```
<?php echo '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'; ?>
```

vs.

```
<?php
  /* some code */
?><h1><?php echo 'Hello world'; ?></h1><?php
  /* more code */
?>
```

Both do the same thing, but one uses PHP to write html; the other escapes PHP, writes html, goes back to PHP and echos a string, then escapes it again to close the tag.

Comment: Wow, hands are failing me. Must be bed time... ;p

Comment: "the other escapes PHP, writes html, goes back to PHP and echos a string, then escapes it again to close the tag."... then jumps through hoops, bounces off walls, and does figure 8's in the parking lot. :-D

Comment: @Herbert: it also makes my coffee every morning and pays for my gas. (<3 php)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<?php
   echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
?>
```

or you can try like

```
<h1><?php echo "Hello World";?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>"; ?>
```

Another way by stripping HTML with Server Side code  -

```
<h1><?php echo "Hello World"; ?></h1>
```

Even this too works -

```
<h1><?php echo "Hello World" ?></h1>
```

(Bb careful here, read below)Performance wise `''` single quotes are better than `""` if only text -

```
<h1><?php echo 'Hello World'; ?></h1>
```

**EDIT**-

[Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html](http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html)

Courtesy - [JACK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack)

Comment: You have too many quotes in the first one.

Comment: @Herbert lol yeah bad edit

Comment: "stripping HTML with Server Side code" ??

Comment: @Blorgbeard just as a side note to handle HTML and PHP server side code separately

Comment: Don't really understand the down votes on this one. Is it somehow worse than the than the others? +1 to counter.

Comment: +1 for you @swapnesh....small mistakes happens but nobody will miss the nice ans...may be its more detail than me...

Comment: @Gautam3164 lol that ok..we can always take down our posts on too many downvotes :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
  ?>
```

Note: 
 everything html goes inside the echo " <<>>>"; 
 The exception is echo "click here";
A string is represented by whatever is inside a pair of " ", not anything after of before it.